# Same HMAC algorithm in obj-c and swift creates different hashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, hmac

I have two methods that create a sha1 hash from a string. Using the same input data this algorithms create different hashes, however they should create the same hashes.

In swift (creates 617fb90f14f2eacecc333d558237bf8bb9fc85f7):

```
static func sha1FromMessage(message: String) -> String {

    let cKey = RestUtils.API_KEY.cStringUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    let cData = message.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    var cHMAC = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cKey, UInt(cKey.count), cData, UInt(cData.count), &cHMAC)

    let output = NSMutableString(capacity: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    for byte in cHMAC {
        output.appendFormat("%02hhx", byte)
    }

    return output
}
```

and obj-c (creates d80b816f0b46d5211b6d9487089597e181717ea6)

```
+(NSString *)sha1FromMessage:(NSString *)message{

    const char *cKey  = [API_KEY cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [message cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSData *HMACData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

    const unsigned char *buffer = (const unsigned char *)[HMACData bytes];
    NSMutableString *HMAC = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:HMACData.length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < HMACData.length; ++i){
        [HMAC appendFormat:@"%02hhx", buffer[i]];
    }

    return HMAC;
}
```

I would like the swift method to return the same hash as the obj-c method. Any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `cData` created by

```
let cData = message.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

includes the *terminating NUL-character* of the message string and that is counted in
`UInt(cData.count)` as well. You could fix that by using `UInt(strlen(cData))` instead,
as in your Objective-C code.

But a better solution is to convert the input strings
to `NSData` objects instead:

```
let cKey = RestUtils.API_KEY.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
let cData = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

var cHMAC = [CUnsignedChar](count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), cKey.bytes, UInt(cKey.length), cData.bytes, UInt(cData.length), &cHMAC)
```

With this modification, Swift and Objective-C code produce the same message digest.

Comment: Tested it, hashes are still different. Swift (6670b90fe993291b741e4ce7905deb0811fec084) and obj-c(d80b816f0b46d5211b6d9487089597e181717ea6) while having the same input.

Comment: @artworkadシ: Can you give a concrete key and message where the result is different? Then I could try to find the problem. – I had tested it with key="key" and message="message" and got identical results 2088df74d5f2146b48146caf4965377e9d0be3a4. – Perhaps the key has embedded NUL characters?

Comment: I found the problem. There is an issue with cKey. When I set cKey = "test" I get the same hash. However when I set cKey = "a32d2...f25" (96 in length) I get different hashes, however cKey has the same value for the swift and obj-c version of the code. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @artworkadシ: I just noticed (and fixed) a typo in my answer, the first `UInt(cData.length)` should be `UInt(cKey.length)`, so that might have been the problem.